# Error: Nullable object must have a value after migrating to .NET 6

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I had a running code in .NET Core 3.1, but after migrating to .NET 6 I get this error. Underline database and the data is also same as previous.

> Nullable object must have a value

I have two separate linq queries and both return an `IQueryable<>`. Then at last again joining both query and getting result from database.

Code:

```
var query1 = from t1 in Table1    
             join t2 in Table2 on t1.Id equals t2.Id into join2
             from t2 in join2.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join t3 in Table3 on t1.Id equals t3.Id into join3
             from t3 in join3.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join t4 in Table4 on t1.Id equals t4.Id into join4
             from t4 in join4.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { t1, t2, t3, t4 };

var query2 = from t5 in Table5    
             join t6 in Table6 on t5.Id equals t6.Id into join6
             from t6 in join6.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join t7 in Table7 on t5.Id equals t7.Id into join7
             from t7 in join7.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join t8 in Table8 on t5.Id equals t8.Id into join8
             from t8 in join8.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { t5, t6, t7, t8 };

var query3 = from q1 in query1
             join q2 in query2 on q1.t1.Id equals q2.t5.Id
             select new ResponseObject
                        {
                            Field1 = q1.t1.Field1,
                            Field2 = q1.t2.Field2,
                            Field3 = q1.t3.Field3,
                            Field4 = q1.t4.Field4,
                            Field5 = q2.t5.Field5,
                            Field6 = q2.t6.Field6,
                            Field7 = q2.t7.Field7,
                            Field8 = q2.t8.Field8,
                        };

// Exception is thrown on this line
var result = query3.ToList();
```

I got to know the cause as sometime t2/t3/t4 and t6/t7/t8 can be null and when trying to access the properties of those it's throwing error. But I want to know how this was working before .NET Core version upgrade.

There is nothing mentioned in breaking changes of .NET 6 / EF Core 6. So how to handle this as I have this kind of query in many places in our code.

I also tried to use `Null Propagating Operator (?)` in select,

```
select new ResponseObject
{
    Field3 = q1?.t1?.Field3,
    Field4 = q1?.t2?.Field4
    .
    .
    .
           
};
```

but that throws a compile-time error

> An expression tree may not contain a null propagating operator

Comment: Which types has filkers `q1.t1.Field`, etc,? Try to explicitly define nullability during projection `Field1 = (int?)q1.t1.Field1`.

Comment: Are all of the fields that might be null null-able in your ResponseObject? if the Field1, 2, etc. can be null in the source entities (due to the field or relationship being #null), ensure these are marked as nullable in ResponseObject. For instance, strings. Previously you likely would have already used `int?` for integer values you expect could be null. Now you need to use `string?` for null-able strings to avoid warnings and errors.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, in my case t1 itself is null. Field1 is nullable only no issues for that

Comment: Show exception call stack. And check nullability of fields in table `t1`. With hypothetical query and model we cannot advise anything.

Answer (score -1):

For

> An expression tree may not contain a null propagating operator

`IQueryable<>` uses expression trees so you can do it the old way without null propagating.

```
select new ResponseObject
{
    Field3 = q1 == null ? null : q1.t1 == null ? null : q1.t1.Field3,
}
```